# Angular multicard crousel with center card as focus

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have got the code for multi card from:

https://www.codeply.com/go/EIOtI7nkP8

The above code displays multiple cards, i need 3 cards such that everytime the crousel moves and the third card comes at center i can dynamically add class to change its css properties. I am making my project on Angular10 and need to use *ngfor to create these cards.

Before Sliding:
[image: Before Slide]

After Sliding:
[image]

The central card must be highlighted.
HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col" *ngFor="let item of fakeArray;let i=index">
  <div class="card" [style.background-color]="color[i]">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="assets/home.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">{{i+1}}</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div></div>
  </div></div>
  </div>
```

```
  fakeArray= new Array(3)
```

I have been stuck at it for past 3 days.
Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I waited for a day and coded for a few days with as i got no answer, I found out that there exists a library swiper js for these kind of components.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/swiper-angular-example?file=src%2Fstyles.scss
You can call a function for on change slide to change the css or class dynamically.